# Apply CSS style to angular componet from within the component

Tags: angular, angular-components, ng-style

If I create a very simple component in angular with the following html:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'grid-column-start':  colStart }" >
  testing
</div>
```

The component typescript file contains 1 input

```
  @Input() colStart: number;
```

I want to use the component within a css grid however when the component in rendered in the dom it's wrapped in a element for the component

```
<app-test-component _ngcontent-fsq-c305="" _nghost-fsq-c298="" ng-reflect-col-start="3">
    <div _ngcontent-fsq-c298="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="grid-column-start: 3;">
        testing
    </div>
</app-test-component>
```

So in the example above I'm trying to position the component within a grid but it doesn't work as the css property in on the div and not the component.

How can I resolve this?

I've created this StackBlitz to demo the issue:

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ro8ifd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fgrid-item%2Fgrid-item.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fgrid-item%2Fgrid-item.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fgrid-item%2Fgrid-item.component.ts)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your grid-item-component can be like

```
<div class="grid-item">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>


export class GridItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() set colStart(value:number)
  {
    this.el.nativeElement.style['grid-column-start']=value
  }

  constructor(private el:ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Component styles have a few special selectors in Angular, like `:host` and `:host-context` or the power of `[ngClass]`.

```css
.col-3 {
    grid-column-start: 3
}
```

```html
<app-test-component [ngClass]="col-3">
        
</app-test-component>
```

I highly recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: OK but I want to set the number of columns via an input value so the style needs to be set within the component. I've updated the example